# Laravel Firebase image upload assign URL

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

```
    $bucket=$db122->bucket('sale-purchase-f56ba.appspot.com');
    $file1=fopen($request->image, 'r');
    $obj=$bucket->upload(
        $file1,[
            'resumable' => true,
            'name' => $filename,
            'uploadType'=> "media",
            'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead',

        ]
    );
```

plz guide me how to give them a URL after upload image, It also lacks Access Token My uploaded image in Storage also not displaying in Storage

Comment: It would help to provide some context into what the variables in your code snippet are, for instance, my first question is, "What is `db122`? (It's an object of "what" class?).
Providing context helps those that might be able to answer your question.

Comment: $db122= new FirestoreClient([
            'projectId' => 'salePurchase-q12sd',
        ]);

Comment: Dear - Emmanuel-okeke plz guide if you know some thing

Comment: I've never worked with Firebase but I just checked out the documentation and I feel you might be getting something wrong there. Are you certain you `$db122` isn't an instance of `StorageClient`? The solution you're looking for might be a combination of a few things: (1) Putting the object in storage (hopefully with a public ACL set on it) (2) Returning a link that's a combination of the base URL you have for the storage and the key name you set when `put`ting the object in storage. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/src/upload_object.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code snippet below to retrieve a signed url to the image uploaded

```
$expiresAt = new \DateTime('tomorrow');
$storageObject = app('firebase.storage')->getBucket()->object($firebase_storage_path.$name.'.'.$extension);

if ($storageObject->exists()) {
    $imageURL = $storageObject->signedUrl($expiresAt);
} else {
    $imageURL = '';
}

return $imageURL;
```

You can change the expiration period if you wish.